# Convert to expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I convert this method to Expression that I can use in linq to entities:

```
    public bool IsMatch(long additionId)
    {
        return AdditionsPrices.Any(x => x.AdditionId == additionId);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. What is the problem?

Comment: @BrunoLM: I don't know how to convert this method to an expression that can executed on linq to entities in query of an entity framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
public Expression<Func<Addition, bool>> IsMatch(long additionId)
    {
        return a => a.AdditionsPrices.Any(x => x.AdditionId == additionId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do a Contains() query instead - extract a `List<long>` from `AdditionsPrices`:

```
List<long> additionIds = AdditionsPrices.Select( x => x.AdditionId)
                                        .ToList();
```

and then use this in a EF `Contains()` query:

```
var results = context.SomeEntitySet
                     .Where(x => additionIds.Contains(x.AdditionId));
```

Comment: I am going to write a query that uses the IsMatch method. But I always got the exception that linq to entities doesn't recognize the method. So I want to create a new IsMatch method that returns expression. You can see more about my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5845993/289246

Comment: This would require in your case transferring a List of a non-primitive type (`AdditionsPrices`) down to SQL - I don't think this is going to work - of course I might be wrong.

Comment: So you telling there is no way to solve this problem in .NET 4.0?

Comment: @Naor: Not that I am aware of given the dependencies and complexity of the Expression you need - I simply do not know of any mapping to SQL that would give you what you want.