# Wrap the IsNumeric function of SqlFunctions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'd like to wrap the SqlFunctions.IsNumeric function so that I can use it in other layer without the need to add reference to System.Data (no matter why).
Here is what I did -
In my Repository Interfaces:

```
public interface IUtils
{
    Expression<Func<bool>> IsNumeric(string str);
}
```

In my ef layer:

```
public class EFUtils : IUtils
{
    public Expression<Func<bool>> IsNumeric(string str)
    {
        return () => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(str) == 1;
    }
}
```

In my business later:

```
public class RepositoryUtils
{
    protected static IUtils Utils { get; set; }

    static RepositoryUtils()
    {
        Utils = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUtils>(); //Using structureMap
    }

    public static Expression<Func< bool>> IsNumeric(string str)
    {
        return Utils.IsNumeric(str);
    }
}
```

The problem is that now, after I exposed the method, I don't really know how to use it..
It is something like:

```
Customers.OrderBy(x=>**Order by is numeric on x.Name);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry I don't know but can you tell me whatis the "=>" called, what does it do?  I've not seen this syntax.

Comment: @mikey: It is actually syntax of lambda expression which is syntactic suagr to delegates. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
Customers.OrderBy(x=>RepositoryUtils.IsNumeric(x.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RepositoryUtils` returns `Expression<Func<bool>>`, so it should be like this:

```
Customers.OrderBy(x => RepositoryUtils.IsNumeric(x.Name).Compile()());
```

By this code you compile the lambda expression and then call it.

**UPD.** I don't see for what purpose `Expression<Func<bool>>` is used. I'd use a simple bool:

```
public class EFUtils : IUtils
{
    public bool IsNumeric(string str)
    {
        return SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(str) == 1;
    }
}

public class RepositoryUtils
{
    protected static IUtils Utils { get; set; }

    static RepositoryUtils()
    {
        Utils = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUtils>(); //Using structureMap
    }

    public static bool IsNumeric(string str)
    {
        return Utils.IsNumeric(str);
    }
}
```

Then the lambda expression will be simpler:

```
Customers.OrderBy(x => RepositoryUtils.IsNumeric(x.Name));
```

Comment: @Centro: I get the exception: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities...

Comment: @Naor Where exactly do you have an exception?

Comment: @Centro: Later I do query.Count() for example and this throws the exception. Your update is better but I still get this exception: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
I am using lambda and the exception explains I need to use linq to entities instead. Do you know how to work around this so I can use lambda?

Comment: @Naor There seem to be specifics for lambda expressions for Entity Framework there. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845993/linq-to-entities-doesnt-recognize-a-method) for more information.

Comment: @Centro: The link you gave me is a question I asked and I can't find there something that will help me..

Comment: @Naor Did you try to directly use `SqlFunctions.IsNumeric` - `Customers.OrderBy(x => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(x.Name) == 1)` - does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work this way. I believe the expression itself should look like:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> YourNewExpression(T something)
```

not only

```
Expression<Func<bool>> YourNewExpression(T something)
```

that is nothing. If you want to pass expression to `OrderBy` you don't pass:

```
.OrderBy(x => YourNewExpression(x))
```

You must pass:

```
.OrderBy(YourNewExpression)
```

Which leads to a problem in reusability because if you want to pass `string` to the expression you can use it only on `IQueryable<string>`. I'm not sure if it can be somehow tweaked to work. This is just explanation why it doesn't work.