# Convert Method. "The specified method on the type cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, postgresql

I'd migrated my entity 6.0 project from SQL Server to PostGreSQL. With SQL Server, these kind of convertion on my queries used to work properlly

**Module.cs**

```
return (
    from m in objDB.Modules
    orderby m.ID
    select new
    {
        ID = m.ID,
        Name = m.Name,
        Status = DB_Function.Convert.ToInt32( m.Status )
    }
);
```

PS: Status is a boolean type

**DB_Function.cs**

```
[System.Data.Entity.DbFunctionAttribute( "Business.Database", "ToInt32" )]
public static Int32 ToInt32( Boolean Val )
{
    return System.Convert.ToInt32( Val );
}
```

However, when I migrated to PostgreSQL (and therefore changed my EDMX), these kind of conversion don't execute anymore:

> The specified method 'Int32 ToInt32(Boolean)' on the type
>   'DB_Function+Convert' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities
>   store expression.

This error is related with PostGre (like int4 and not int32) or I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you converting to `Int32` if `Status` is a boolean?

Comment: Because I need it with 0 and 1. In SQL Server, there is no type boolean, just bit, so this conversion was just for the bit value became int32. Although, in PostGre there is a type boolean, but all the code was programmed to work with 0 or 1, so I'm trying not to modify it drastically.

Comment: Could you change the method to be `return Val ? 1 : 0;` instead?

Comment: I try with this but still returning the same error message. Now I'm with more doubts, i thought that your solution would fit like a glove. Maybe the problem is with the calling of the method. Thanks anyway for that.

Edit: I have modified the linq itself and works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not to change the subject, but if you used a bit field in Sql Server, it would have by mapped it to a boolean for you in Entity Framework.  And the function you have should work (I think, never used postgres with EF) *IF* postgres has a function called "ToInt32".  Did you not create that function in the database?

Comment: I guess that I didn't undestand your comment but yes, that method that I shown was created by me. There is no native "ToInt32" even with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For understanding what type of functions we can use inside LINQ to Enitities : go through below linK :
[linq to entities doesn't recognize a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845993/linq-to-entities-doesnt-recognize-a-method)

Now In this particular case we were having a function in side LINQ to Entites, which was unable to be translated to SQL Query and hence the Exception was thrown. SO by removing the function it work perfectly.

return (
        from m in objDB.Modules
        orderby m.ID
        select new
        {
            ID = m.ID,
            Name = m.Name,
            Status =  m.Status == true ? 1 : 0
        }
    );

Comment: While this may answer the question it would be helpful for the asker if you included comments in your code and/or include an additional explanation instead of providing a code-only answer.

Comment: Additional explanation would improve your answer.

Comment: Yea sure will keep in mind..  next time onwards.. currently editing the answer with comment:)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove your function and it will work if your values is not nullable

```
return (
from m in objDB.Modules
orderby m.ID
select new
   {
    ID = m.ID,
    Name = m.Name,
    Status = Convert.ToInt32( m.Status )
   }
);
```

If it is nullable you will need to check if it has value:

```
return (
from m in objDB.Modules
orderby m.ID
select new
   {
    ID = m.ID,
    Name = m.Name,
    Status =m.Status.HasValue? Convert.ToInt32( m.Status ):0
   }
);
```

Comment: With this, the same message is shown:

**" LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. "**

That exactly why I've created the **"ToInt32( Boolean Val )"** method that I comment above. With these method it works on SQL but no with PostGre (or at least, no with the new modified EDMX that I had to created to PostGre works).

Thanks anyway.